# Find the function value at the point knowing it's non-integrable derivative value at the point

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Screenshot of the task I'm trying to solve
[image: Screenshot of the task I'm trying to solve]

Hello, guys. Can somebody help me to find the right way to solve this problem (problem I'm trying to solve is depicted on the attached image)? How should I use graphing calculator for the problem? Have no idea, please give me a hint! I tried to find integral for the h'(x) but it seems not to be solvable... So as a result I can not define h(x) as "something + C" to find value of C. How can I find value of C in my case, using graphic calculator? Or maybe there is another way I should go to solve this problem?

Comment: **Hint:** $$h(1)=\int_{-5}^1h'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+h(-5)$$

Comment: Wow, so easy. As I can understand, roughly, definite integral from -1 to 5 of derivative gives us the value of h(6), and then we add h(-5) to it, and the result will be h(1)? Did I understand your solution hint correctly?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you understand. The fundamental theorem of calculus means that $$\int_{-5}^1 h'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=h(1)-h(-5)$$I just rearranged this result to get what you required.